# how to create thumbnail of size 480 X 640 using python pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am new to python. I tried with this bellow code but it is not creating with my thumbnail size.

```
# Open the original image of size 1500X1500 
original_image = Image.open("TM16224-1.jpg")

# Create a thumbnail with a maximum size of 480x640 while preserving the aspect ratio
original_image.thumbnail((480, 640))

# Save the thumbnail
original_image.save("thumbnail_image.png")

# Optionally, you can also display the thumbnail
original_image.show()


please help.
```

Comment: If you want to create an image exactly 480x640 you cannot do that while retaining the 1:1 aspect ratio of a 1500x1500 original. If you want to change the aspect ratio, use `resize()`.

Answer (score 0):

To create a thumbnail of size 480 x 640 using the Python Pillow library, you can use the thumbnail() method.

```
from PIL import Image

# Open the original image
original_image = Image.open("your_image_path.jpg")

# Set the desired thumbnail size
thumbnail_size = (480, 640)

# Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions without maintaining the aspect ratio
thumbnail_image = original_image.resize(thumbnail_size)

# Save the thumbnail
thumbnail_image.save("output_thumbnail.jpg")
```

By using the resize method, the image will be resized to the exact dimensions specified in thumbnail_size without maintaining the original aspect ratio. Adjust the paths and filenames according to your requirements.

Comment: i tried this . it just create thumbnail of 480 X 480 . i need 480 X 640 exactly.